# how to create a custom component with a xml file android

Tags: java, android, xml, file, custom-component

I have an xml file and I want to change it to a component by using a class which extends View.
how Can I do that ??

java code :

```
public class custom extends View {

public custom(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

public custom(Context context , AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context , attrs);
}
```

}

and this is my xml code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.apd.ecryptfolders.custom">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a class that extends layout root view and then inflate the xml layout

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout {
    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.layout_name, null);
        addView(view);
        // init layout
    }
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.layout_name, null);
        addView(view);
        // here you can apply custom attributes
        // init layout
    }
}
```

These links can help you:

- https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components